# How to get the type of element / tag type in selenium c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, selenium

Say for example I have a tag as :

```
<a class = "fp-anchor fp-forgot-password pull-right" href = "/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a> == $0
```

I am trying to get the type of element for this by which I mean should be an anchor `a` tag. Or more precisely, I need to identify if this is a hyperlink. 
Something like,

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid")).<whatever selenium webdriver function to identify what type of element it is>
```

Similarly if it is an input tag, say

```
<input type="text"..../>
```

It should identify the tag as an `input` type.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get the tag name using `.TagName;` property

e.g.

```
string tagname = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid")).TagName;
```

Comment: the function GetTagName oes not appear in my case.

Comment: @BishwaroopChakraborty, Try this `TagName` e.g. `string tagname = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid")).TagName` let me know if it is working in C#